# Unreadable character in generated sqlplus file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a shell with one command line opening sql plus and calling a sql file

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus id/psw @SQL_DIRECTORY/myfile.sql
```

in this file I write this :

```
spool myfile.csv

select 'column 01', ';', 'column 02' from dual;
select myColumn1, ';', mycolum2 from mytable

spool off
```

It works good BUT on the first line of the the first column of each select there is a special character.

Why is that? how can I get rid of this

Thanks

Comment: what is the special character ? are you saying something related to character set ? useally for uf8 encoding it leave a hidden character

Comment: I see it under notepad ++, dont know what it is, can see it with Excel (a question mark in a square. I dont use utf8 but iso8859-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description it sounds like you have a `login.sql` or `glogin.sql` [user profile](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e27507/sqlplus.htm#DFSUG138) that is issuing [`set newpage 0`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG091):

> Sets the number of blank lines to be printed from the top of each page to the top title. **A value of zero places a formfeed at the beginning of each page** (including the first page) and clears the screen on most terminals. If you set NEWPAGE to NONE, SQL*Plus does not print a blank line or formfeed between the report pages.

In Excel that does show up as an unprintable character with a question mark in a small square; in Notepad++ it seems to show as `FF` in reverse colouring; and in some editors (e.g. Vim) it shows as `^L`. This is the [ASCII form feed](http://www.asciitable.com) character, decimal 12 or 0xC.

You can either reset that with `set newpage none`, or make it irrelevant with `set pagesize 0`, which has the convenient side effect of removing the column headers and separators. You may also want to `set feedback off` if you aren't already.

Samples with contrasting settings:

```
set newpage 0;
set feedback on;
set pagesize 100;

spool ctrl.csv
select 'head 1;head 2' from dual;
select sysdate, ';', systimestamp from dual;
spool off


^L'HEAD1;HEAD2'
-------------
head 1;head 2

1 row selected.

^LSYSDATE             ' SYSTIMESTAMP
------------------- - ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

2015-09-16 15:45:42 ;  16-SEP-15 15.45.42.333627 +01:00


1 row selected.
```

And

```
set newpage none;
set feedback off;
set pagesize 0;

spool ctrl.csv
select 'head 1;head 2' from dual;
select sysdate, ';', systimestamp from dual;
spool off

head 1;head 2
2015-09-16 15:46:11 ; 16-SEP-15 15.46.11.274863 +01:00
```