# Gibberish filed values when Loading data with Oracle SQL Loader (sqlldr)

Tags: oracle, encoding, oracle11g, sql-loader

Using

> sqlldr

to load data in an oracle table doesn't result in any errors but the value of the fields are gibberish.  not all the values of course, only the values which was in persian(arabic) format.
already read many questions here but could not resolve the issue, most relatable topic to this problem were :[[Unreadable character in generated sqlplus file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611162/unreadable-character-in-generated-sqlplus-file][1])
although the values in my case isn't question mark, but something like ,ÑÇå Âåä or äÇ ãÔÎÕ

Also played with the NLS_LANG environment variable but it was to no avail.

Created different oracle databases with different character set's, this also was to no avail.

I'm new to oracle, so it is highly likely that I'm making a rookie mistake while creating database and setting character set or something else, to be honest i have no idea. but  tried many responses from users and here i am.

I Uploaded the table schema and Ctl extension File to replicate the problem, the link to the related files are resided in this link: [https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ejxvast0ruioksk/AABXhjujqzhRpuMVjl7V-zxUa?dl=0][1]

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Windows........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In total you have **three** character sets or encodings.

1. What is the encoding of your file? Check the save options of the editor or the application which created the file.
2. The character set of your command line window `cmd.exe`, called "codepage". You can interrogate (or change) with command `chcp`
3. The character set of your database.

1) and 2) must be the same. Use command `chcp` to set them equal (or change settings in your editor)

3) can be different but the character set must support persian/arabic characters, so most likely `AL32UTF8` which is the default nowadays.

Use the `NLS_LANG` value to tell the database which character set is used for 1) and 2), example

```
C:\>chcp 1256
Aktive Codepage: 1256.

C:\>set NLS_LANG=.AR8MSWIN1256

C:\>sqlldr ...
```

You can get a list of codepages vs. Oracle character set with this query:

```
SELECT VALUE AS ORACLE_CHARSET, UTL_I18N.MAP_CHARSET(VALUE) AS IANA_NAME
FROM V$NLS_VALID_VALUES
WHERE PARAMETER = 'CHARACTERSET';
```

And here a list of [Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx)

See also [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600) to get more details.

Comment: Hello , I created two database one is 
NLS_CHARACTERSET                 AR8ISO8859P6                                                    
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET           AL16UTF16 , 
the other one is 
NLS_CHARACTERSET                 WE8MSWIN1252                                                    
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET           AL16UTF16  


also is set the chcp to 1256 and 1252 but it didnt work either. any suggesion?

Comment: Strangely i tried on another pc and this time it worked!